# Post thumbnail dependant on category

Tags: posts, images

I have two categories (our work and news) and only one single.php
If looking at a single post in the news category then I want to show the thumbnail too so have inserted:

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('medium');} ?>`

But I dont want this to appear if viewing a single post within the our work category, what can I add to remove this for category ID#2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat = $categories[0]->cat_name;

if ( has_post_thumbnail() && $cat == 'news' ) { the_post_thumbnail('medium'); }
```

**EDIT: the code grabs the post category, line 2 grabs cat name from the object and I use it as a condition in if statement **

Comment: Please explain your code and why you think it will solve the problem rather than just posting the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. It will work even if you assign multiple categories to posts.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && has_category('news') ) {  // or !has_category('our-work')
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
}
```